# What exactly is "DepCompareOp"?

Tags: debian, package-management

There are a lot of pages, asking how to fix "W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp".

But what is "DepCompareOp" itself? I understand, that it relates to misconfigured "Provides:" field and somehow relates to packages, that depend on package provided. How can we tell whether "Provides:" is good or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"DepCompareOp" stands for "dependency comparison operator", *i.e.* "=", "<=", ">=", "<<" or ">>", used to compare package versions. The message comes from[`apt`](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/164f1b78d1849a0f33df7352875f86e28f5de06a/apt-pkg/deb/deblistparser.cc#L923), and is printed when a package is encountered with a "Provides" declaration including a non-equal dependency comparison operator, which [is invalid](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html). ([`dpkg` now supports versioned-provides](https://tracker.debian.org/news/562962), which is why [the error message changed](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/commit/40faab46c4d5fa766c80090f0fdb54120dbb37f2) to explicitly mention non-equal operators.)

So basically, a package can declare

```
Provides: some-other-package
```

in its `control` file and be fine, or (since mid-2014)

```
Provides: some-other-package (= version)
```

but not

```
Provides: some-other-package (<< version)
```

In the past, any mention of a version would have caused `apt`-based tools to print

> Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package ...

whereas nowadays only the latter will produce

> Ignoring Provides line with non-equal DepCompareOp for package ...